# Add new column in DataFrame with number of neighbours for another column's value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a a `DataFrame` of this sort:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Timestamp: int, AccX: double ... 17 more fields]`
```

The timestamps are not succesive and are in epoch format.

I would like to add a new column that will have for each row the number of timeStamps that are close to the timestamp of the current Row.

Example :

TimeStamp

```
1
5
6
12
13
16
```

Imagine we have a range of 3. The output would be :

```
|      TimeStamp      |    New column    |
|          1          |         1        |
|          5          |         2        |
|          6          |         2        |
|          12         |         2        |
|          13         |         3        |
|          16         |         2        |
```

I was thinking of doing something  like :

```
MyDF.map{x => MyDF.filter(MyDF("Timestamp").gt(x.getAs[Int]("Timestamp") - range).lt(x.getAs[Int]("Timestamp") + range) ).count()}
```

but this leavesmewith a : `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [value: bigint]`

which I do not know how to handle.

Does any one have a better idea of how this can be processed ?

Thanks

**Update :**
I am using a zeppelin notebook running Spark version 2.1.1
After trying the solution proposed by @Dennis Tsoi, I get an error when trying to perform actions on the resulting Dataframe such as show or collect.

Here is the full text of error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2104)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:841)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:840)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex(RDD.scala:840)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec.doExecute(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:371)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:228)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:311)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2386)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2788)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2385)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2392)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2128)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2818)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2342)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:638)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:597)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:606)
  ... 88 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec, value: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@79df42d)
    - field (class: $iw, name: windowSpec, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@20ade815)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@77cac38a)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1ebfd642)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1ee19937)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@67b1d8f0)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@16ca3d83)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3129d731)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@142a2936)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@494facc5)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@45e32c0a)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@509c3eb6)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7bba53a2)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@20971db8)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@ba81c26)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@9375cbb)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3226a593)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@201516a3)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1ac15b76)
    - field (class: $line20176553781522.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line20176553781522.$read, $line20176553781522.$read@21cc8115)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $line20176553781522$read, type: class $line20176553781522.$read)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@57677eee)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@1d619339)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@63f875)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@2a8641fe)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@279b1062)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@2a06eb02)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6071a045)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@36b8b963)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@49987884)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6cdfa5ad)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@3bea2150)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@7d1c7dc)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@78f47403)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@6327d388)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@5d120092)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@4da8dd9c)
    - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $iw, $iw@2afee9a4)
    - field (class: $line20176553782370.$read, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
    - object (class $line20176553782370.$read, $line20176553782370.$read@7112605e)
    - field (class: $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw, name: $line20176553782370$read, type: class $line20176553782370.$read)
    - object (class $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw, $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw@cc82e3c)
    - field (class: $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw, name: $outer, type: class $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw)
    - object (class $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw, $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw@9ec8a4e)
    - field (class: $$$$7f619eaa173efe86d354fc4efb19aab8$$$$$anonfun$1, name: $outer, type: class $$$$24338a4fbcb24dc6d683541cf6403767$$$$iw)
    - object (class $$$$7f619eaa173efe86d354fc4efb19aab8$$$$$anonfun$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, name: func$2, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(input[0, int, true]))
    - element of array (index: 0)
    - array (class [Ljava.lang.Object;, size 1)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, name: references$1, type: class [Ljava.lang.Object;)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8, <function2>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:10
0)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
  ... 121 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Unbatched lookup operations like `dt` and `lt` can be quite expensive so I've come up with the following solution.

```
val timestampsDF = 
    Seq(
        ( 1, "smth1" ),
        ( 5, "smth2" ),
        ( 6, "smth3" ),
        ( 12, "smth4" ),
        ( 13, "smth5" ),
        ( 16, "smth6" )
    )
    .toDF( "TimeStamp", "smth" )

val timestampsStatic = 
    timestampsDF
    .select("TimeStamp")
    .as[ ( Int ) ]
    .collect()

def countNeighbors = udf( ( currentTs: Int, timestamps: Seq[ Int ] ) => {

    timestamps.count( ( ts ) => Math.abs( currentTs - ts ) <= 3 )
} )

val alltimeDF = 
    timestampsDF
    .withColumn( 
        "All TimeStamps", 
        lit( timestampsStatic )
    )

val neighborsDF =
    alltimeDF
    .withColumn( 
        "New Column", 
        countNeighbors( alltimeDF( "TimeStamp" ), alltimeDF( "All TimeStamps" ) )
    )
    .drop( "All TimeStamps" )

neighborsDF.show()
```

Results

```
+---------+-----+----------+
|TimeStamp| smth|New Column|
+---------+-----+----------+
|        1|smth1|         1|
|        5|smth2|         2|
|        6|smth3|         2|
|       12|smth4|         2|
|       13|smth5|         3|
|       16|smth6|         2|
+---------+-----+----------+
```

### Memory consumption concern

Since only dataframe **rows** are accessible on nodes you have to copy all timestamps from original DF to another column as static field. That would lead to increase in memory consumption but you can't access ALL column values from UDF, only those from corresponding rows. Anyway, I think it is the true "spark way".

Comment: Hi @Dennis, Thanks for your answer. I have tried this same method it goes well but I keep getting : `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` when trying to use show() on it **or any other action** .

Comment: I couldn't replicate the error in my Zeppelin but I think it may be due to implicit closure boundaries I used in udf. Try the new code.

Comment: Hello Dennis,
I have tried your new idea but there is an issue with it. Applying an action in side another transformation is not allowed. 
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: This RDD lacks a SparkContext. It could happen in the following cases:
 And I believe it is linked to SPARK-5063. : `RDD transformations and actions are NOT invoked by the driver, but inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation`

Comment: @Azzy, sorry about misleading information. I forgot that udfs are limited in their scope to row data. I updated the answer with better solution.